# Wordpress Content getting commented out and not showing up

Tags: wordpress

The code is there but there is some weird code that is commenting it out:
http://canvasranch.com/wordpress/blog/

```
<div role="main" id="content">
  <div class="post-40 page type-page status-publish hentry" id="post-40">  
      <!--h1 class="entry-title"><!--?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <div class="entry-content">
        <p>test test</p>
        <span class="edit-link"><a class="post-edit-link" href="http://website.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=40&amp;action=edit" title="Edit Page">Edit</a></span>
      </div><!-- .entry-content -->
  </div><!-- #post-## -->
</div> <!-- end div main -->
```

Comment: Wow, that's an amazing amount of editing just to avoid the `{}` code-formatting button in the text editor.

Comment: @bmp415 - what sarnold is getting at is that you can post html on SO. You just need to code block it. There is a `{}` button in the editor that will do this for you. You can also manually do it by prepending a line of code with four spaces or by surroung it with `backticks` `

Comment: @mrtsherman - thank you... my first question on stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that all you need to do to fix this is fix the comment tags. Unless this is being programmatically entered from somewhere else. This is unclear from your question.

Replace `<!--` at the beginning of the h1 tag with just `<` and remove the other comment blocks `<!--` or '-->`

```
<div role="main" id="content">
  <div class="post-40 page type-page status-publish hentry" id="post-40">  
      <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <div class="entry-content">
        <p>test test</p>
        <span class="edit-link"><a class="post-edit-link" href="http://website.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=40&amp;action=edit" title="Edit Page">Edit</a></span>
      </div><!-- .entry-content -->
  </div><!-- #post-## -->
</div> <!-- end div main -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's been fixed.